# CMake build with Ninja failed on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, ninja

I built a simple project to test whether CMake and Ninja could work on my Windows 10.
There is a cpp file name **test.cpp** that is shown below.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "hello world!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

And if I now just use Ninja with the build.ninja file then it can work successfully. So I began to try CMake with a simple **CMakeLists.txt** file that is shown below.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

project(test)

add_executable(test test.cpp)
```

Then I used the **command**

```
cmake -B build -G Ninja
```

And error occured like this:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 12.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 12.2.0                    
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: path-to-mingw64/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: path-to-mingw64/bin/gcc.exe - broken
CMake Error at path-to-cmake/share/cmake3.24/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:69 (message):
The C compiler

"path-to-mingw64/bin/gcc.exe"

is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: path-to-my-test-project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

[2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_ed5d0.exe
FAILED: cmTC_ed5d0.exe
cmd.exe /C "cd . && path-to-mingw64\bin\gcc.exe CMakeFiles/cmTC_ed5d0.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj -o cmTC_ed5d0.exe -Wl,--out implib,libcmTC_ed5d0.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lkernel32 luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 
-loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.



CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
CMakeLists.txt:5 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "path-to-my-test-project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "path-to-my-test-project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

And there are the **CMakeOutput.log** and **CMakeError.log**

```
The system is: Windows - 10.0.19044 - AMD64
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
Compiler: path-to-mingw64/bin/gcc.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
0


Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "a.exe"

The C compiler identification is GNU, found in 
"path-to-my-test-project/build/CMakeFiles/3.24.2/CompilerIdC/a.exe"

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: path-to-mingw64/bin/c++.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
0


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced 
"a.exe"

The CXX compiler identification is GNU, found in 
"path-to-my-test-project/build/CMakeFiles/3.24.2/CompilerIdCXX/a.exe"
```

And the **CMakeError.log** is too long and I don't know how to show, maybe I need some guidance about this.

And also, the **command**

```
cmake -B build -G "MinGW Makefiles"
```

can work successfully.

Just leave me a comment if you require further information.

---

According to @273K, I add **CMakeError.log** like this.

```
Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: path-to-my-test-project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):path-to-ninja/ninja.exe cmTC_8d485 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_8d485.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj

[2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_8d485.exe

FAILED: cmTC_8d485.exe 

cmd.exe /C "cd . && path-to-mingw64\bin\gcc.exe   CMakeFiles/cmTC_8d485.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj -o cmTC_8d485.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTC_8d485.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

---

Comment: *CMakeError.log is too long* Look for the last error in the file end.

Comment: I got it and will add it to the question, thanks.